# Get all the version of a row in a SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to read all the versions of a list on a site and store them. I would like to do it for the whole row rather than column by column (or item by item). I have seen this here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137360/how-to-get-all-major-versions-of-list-or-library-item-using-c
but cannot get my head around it as none of the oList, items, and listItem does not have "Version" attribute. I have enabled versioning for my list in the SharePoint. Below is my code in C#.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "mypass".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("email@domain", passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;

    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = @"";
    SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listname");

    clientContext.Load(oList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    SP.ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(query);

    clientContext.Load(items);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> dictitem in listItem.FieldValues)
        {
        //Read this key, value and save them in a datatable
        }
    }

}
```

buy using v16 of SharePoint SDK and items.Versions, I get the following error:

```
 Error  CS1061  'ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition
 for 'Versions' and no accessible extension method 'Versions' accepting a
  first argument of type 'ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing
  a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ListItem.Versions Property to get all versions of an item:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.versions

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{ 
        ListItemVersionCollection itemversioncollection = listItem.Versions;
        clientContext.Load(itemversioncollection);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Also, use the latest version of SharePoint SDK if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting here, since this answer popped up when I searched for a solution. There is already a solution in another stackoverflow answer. That answer works also for SP13.

It is based on using:

```
"https://<server>/<site>/_layouts/versions.aspx?list={litsID}&ID=<itemID>"
```

Please see [SharePoint 2013 - Get SPListItem versions via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423657/sharepoint-2013-get-splistitem-versions-via-rest)